# GPS Logger in android

Tags: android, gps

I need a help in working with GPS Logger. I have a toggle button. Where i set it on i need to start the GPS Logger and i need to set logger interval. I need to display the latitude and longitude in sqlite DB and update the DB based on log interval.

Any working sample code will be helpful for me. I have found many sample application. But didn't work. Any sample working links will be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class LocalisationService extends Service
{
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    //Define a listener that responds to location updates
    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener()
    {
        //Called when a new location is found by the network location provider
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            //insertion of the location in the DB
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){return null;}

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        int interval = 1; //Specify the update interval

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, interval, 0, locationListener);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("STOP_LOCALISATION_SERVICE");

        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                stopSelf();
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```